# error after installing to the newest version

Tags: 2sxc

today i upgraded from 8.4.8 to the version 8.11.0 and no i get this error at the admin log

```
AbsoluteURL:/DesktopModules/2sxc/API/view/module/finishinstallation
```

DefaultDataProvider:DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider, DotNetNuke
ExceptionGUID:427fd78f-c59a-4daf-b70e-ae31f45ccb4f
AssemblyVersion:
PortalId:-1
UserId:-1
TabId:-1
RawUrl:
Referrer:
UserAgent:
ExceptionHash:UKcEMk5XpbIq87lO89Vv5Q==
Message:Der Typeninitialisierer für "ExtentPlaceholderCreator" hat eine Ausnahme verursacht.
StackTrace:
   bei System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.Propagator.ExtentPlaceholderCreator.GetPropagatorResultForPrimitiveType(PrimitiveType primitiveType, PropagatorResult& result)
   bei System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.Propagator.ExtentPlaceholderCreator.Visit(EdmMember node)
   bei System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.Propagator.ExtentPlaceholderCreator.CreateEntitySetPlaceholder(EntitySet entitySet)
   bei System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.Propagator.ExtentPlaceholderCreator.CreatePlaceholder(EntitySetBase extent, UpdateTranslator parent)
   bei System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.Propagator.Visit(DbScanExpression node)
   bei System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbScanExpression.Accept[TResultType](DbExpressionVisitor`1 visitor)
   bei System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateExpressionVisitor`1.Visit(DbExpression expression)
   bei System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.Propagator.Visit(DbProjectExpression node)
   bei System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbProjectExpression.Accept[TResultType](DbExpressionVisitor`1 visitor)
   bei System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.Propagator.Propagate(UpdateTranslator parent, EntitySet table, DbQueryCommandTree umView)
   bei System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.d__0.MoveNext()
   bei System.Linq.Enumerable.d__71`1.MoveNext()
   bei System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateCommandOrderer..ctor(IEnumerable`1 commands, UpdateTranslator translator)
   bei System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.ProduceCommands()
   bei System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
   bei System.Data.EntityClient.EntityAdapter.Update(IEntityStateManager entityCache)
   bei System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
   bei ToSic.Eav.BLL.EavDataController.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options, OriginalSaveChangesEvent baseEvent) in C:\Projects\eav-server\ToSic.Eav\BLL\EavDataController.cs:Zeile 233.
   bei ToSic.Eav.EavContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options) in C:\Projects\eav-server\ToSic.Eav.Persistence.EF4\Persistence\EavContext.cs:Zeile 27.
   bei System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges()
   bei ToSic.Eav.Persistence.DbAttributeSet.EnsureSharedAttributeSets() in C:\Projects\eav-server\ToSic.Eav\BLL\Parts\DbAttributeSet.cs:Zeile 185.
   bei ToSic.Eav.Import.Import.ImportAttributeSet(ImportAttributeSet importAttributeSet) in C:\Projects\eav-server\ToSic.Eav\ImportExport\Import.cs:Zeile 197.
   bei ToSic.Eav.Import.Import.ImportSomeAttributeSets(IEnumerable`1 newAttributeSets, DbTransaction transaction) in C:\Projects\eav-server\ToSic.Eav\ImportExport\Import.cs:Zeile 131.
   bei ToSic.Eav.Import.Import.RunImport(IEnumerable`1 newAttributeSets, IEnumerable`1 newEntities) in C:\Projects\eav-server\ToSic.Eav\ImportExport\Import.cs:Zeile 124.
   bei ToSic.SexyContent.ImportExport.XmlImport.ImportXml(Int32 zoneId, Int32 appId, XDocument doc, Boolean leaveExistingValuesUntouched) in C:\Projects\2SexyContent\Web\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\SexyContent\ImportExport\XmlImport.cs:Zeile 281.
   bei ToSic.SexyContent.Installer.Helpers.ImportXmlSchemaOfVersion(String version, Boolean leaveOriginalsUntouched) in C:\Projects\2SexyContent\Web\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\SexyContent\Installer\Helpers.cs:Zeile 61.
   bei ToSic.SexyContent.Installer.InstallationController.UpgradeModule(String version) in C:\Projects\2SexyContent\Web\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\SexyContent\Installer\InstallationController.cs:Zeile 197.
   bei ToSic.SexyContent.Installer.InstallationController.FinishAbortedUpgrade() in C:\Projects\2SexyContent\Web\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\SexyContent\Installer\InstallationController.cs:Zeile 230.
   bei ToSic.SexyContent.WebApi.View.ModuleController.FinishInstallation() in C:\Projects\2SexyContent\Web\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\WebApi\View\ModuleController.cs:Zeile 347.
   bei lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   bei System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
   bei System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
   bei System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bei System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.d__18`1.MoveNext()
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bei System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bei System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.d__18`1.MoveNext()
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bei System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bei System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext()
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bei System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext()
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bei System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.d__0.MoveNext()
InnerMessage:Ein Aufrufziel hat einen Ausnahmefehler verursacht.
InnerStackTrace:
   bei System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   bei System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   bei System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   bei System.Data.SqlClient.SqlSpatialServices.GeometryFromText(String geometryText)
   bei System.Data.Spatial.DbGeometry.FromText(String wellKnownText)
   bei System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.Propagator.ExtentPlaceholderCreator.InitializeTypeDefaultMap()
   bei System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.Propagator.ExtentPlaceholderCreator..cctor()
Source:System.Data.Entity
FileName:
FileLineNumber:0
FileColumnNumber:0
Method:
Server-Name: web14

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a problem with an incompatible DLL on the server, and was fixed - for anybody interested in the resolution, check out the github issue: https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/issues/1136